# Oracle Sql query Group by Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

MY_TABLE = Table with 2 columns Number, City.
Desired Output = City and count of unique Number associated to the city. Seattle, Bellevue is part of Combined. Even though there are 4 numbers associated to Seattle, Bellevue the output is 3 as there are only 3 distinct numbers - 123, 456, 786.

```
  MY_TABLE
Number   City
123  Seattle
456  Bellevue
789  LosAngeles
780  LosAngeles
123  Bellevue
786  Bellevue
```

Desired Output:

```
Combined 3
LosAngeles 2
```

Query so far:

```
SELECT NUMBER, CITY FROM MY_TABLE WHERE LOOKUP_ID=100 AND CITY IN 
('Seattle', 'Bellevue', 'LosAngeles')
GROUP BY NUMBER, CITY
```

Would highly appreciate if anyone provides a recommendations around the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
SELECT (case when city IN ('Seattle', 'Bellevue') 
             then 'Combined'
             else city
          end) city,
       count( distinct number ) 
  FROM my_table
 WHERE lookup_id = 100
   AND city IN ('Seattle', 'Bellevue', 'LosAngeles')
 GROUP BY (case when city IN ('Seattle', 'Bellevue') 
                then 'Combined'
                else city
           end)
```

Of course, my guess is that you have some other table that tells you which `CITY` values need to be combined rather than having a hard-coded `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
with t as (
SELECT (
        case when city IN ('Seattle', 'Bellevue') 
        then 'Combined'
        else city
        end
    ) city, number from my_table
)
select city, count(distinct number) from t
group by city
```

Tell please, if it was useful

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  (CASE CITY
  WHEN 'Seattle' THEN ‘Combined’ 
  WHEN 'Bellevue' THEN ‘Combined’ 
  ELSE CITY 
  END), COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  MY_TABLE 
WHERE 
  LOOKUP_ID=100 AND CITY IN ('Seattle', 'Bellevue', 'LosAngeles') 
GROUP BY 
   NUMBER, 
   (CASE CITY
    WHEN 'Seattle' THEN ‘Combined’ 
    WHEN 'Bellevue' THEN ‘Combined’ 
    ELSE CITY 
    END)
```

that should do what you asked for, but I suspect that you have some other tables where you define which cities should be considered the same, in such a case you'll need to join on those tables

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 answers already and none of them are generic for more cities.
Try this:

```
SELECT City, COUNT(Number) AS ExclusiveNumbers
FROM (SELECT q2.City, q2.CityNumCount, b.Number
      FROM MY_Table b INNER JOIN
           (SELECT c.City, MAX(NumOccurs) AS CityNumCount
            FROM My_Table c INNER JOIN
                             (SELECT Number, COUNT(City) AS NumOccurs
                              FROM My_Table
                              GROUP BY Number) q1 ON c.Number = q1.Number
            GROUP BY c.City) q2 ON b.City = q2.City) q3
WHERE CityNumCount = 1
GROUP BY City
UNION
SELECT 'Combined', COUNT(DISTINCT Number)
FROM (SELECT q2.City, q2.CityNumCount, b.Number
      FROM MY_Table b INNER JOIN
           (SELECT c.City, MAX(NumOccurs) AS CityNumCount
            FROM My_Table c INNER JOIN
                             (SELECT Number, COUNT(City) AS NumOccurs
                              FROM My_Table
                              GROUP BY Number) q1 ON c.Number = q1.Number
            GROUP BY c.City) q2 ON b.City = q2.City) q3
WHERE CityNumCount > 1
```

The top half of the union works out, for each City name that has no numbers in common with any other city, how many different numbers it has.
The bottom half works out the count of different numbers for cities that do have numbers in common with other cities. These 2 figures will always add up to the count of distinct numbers in the original table.